# Undelete fixed answer

Tags: discussion

Please review my edit to the deleted answer on the following post, to determine if it can now be undeleted. Thank you.

[Emacs - visual-line-mode except in tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39696806/visual-line-mode-except-in-tables)

Comment: Shouldn't the OP have put that effort in, not someone else..? If you wanted to contribute, you should have posted a *new* answer.

Comment: Yes, he should have, but the Edit button is there to fix issues when the OP doesn't know the rules. The idea (and thus answer) remains his, I believe that he should get the rep for upvotes to that answer, not me. I would not have discovered the package without his (deleted) answer.

Comment: There's a big difference between fixing a question to fix formatting issue and moving content from the comment to the question/answer (as they should have been an edit) and writing the OP's answer for them when it was previously a link only answer.

Comment: Also you're edit is a copy of the link the OP original had; that's plagiarism (you make no attempt to demonstrate that the words are not the OP's own). I've personally rolled it back as such, as it conflicts with the OP's original intent (a link only answer) and makes it appear that the text/image is the OP's own when it isn't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, firstly, this wasn't an edit you should have done; it was something for the OP to do. Yes, there is an edit feature, but the main thing you find yourself using this for is fixing tags, spelling/grammar corrections, formatting, typographical corrections (when it isn't the cause of the question) and/or adding context from the comments into the post (as they should have been an edit). Editing a post to significantly change the intent is not an "ok" edit reason, and it is actually a reason for rejection in the review queue (you have more than enough reputation to unilaterally edit with no review).

Also the content you posted is plagiarised from the link the OP originally posted; that is **not** ok. Yes, there is a link there, but there is no attempt in your edit to attempt to demonstrate that the words are not your own, nor the OP's; this is plagiarism.

As such I have rolled back your edit, as I strongly disagree with the intentions you made. The answer is still deleted, and should be, as it's a link only answer (the OP needs to address that).

Instead, you should post your own answer, with your own words, to answer the question; you can cite the link the OP used, but do *not* make it appear those words are your own. Instead quote the link (in a block quote) and expand, using your own words, on the content you have copied.

*Side note, if you were performing a good edit you should also remove any noise;* "Ancient question, but " *should have been removed as it's not needed. There's no need to remove it from the answer as it stands, however, as it's deleted and need far more improvement.*

Comment: Thank you Larnu. I'll add a new answer as you have suggested.